# Ruby program halted in gdb fails to resume after writing to any IO using rb_eval_string

Tags: ruby, gdb

I'm using gdb to try to track down a memory leak in a ruby program.
I'm trying to print some debug data (or write it to a file), and it appears that any time anything is printed to any IO, the program fails to resume after I detach.

The simple test case is a program as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

counter = 0
loop do
  puts "#{counter}\n"
  counter += 1
  sleep 1
end
```

I then attach gdb to the process via `gdb -p PID` and run `p rb_eval_string("$stderr.puts(\"hi\\n\")")` on the gdb console. This causes the failure to resume after detaching. If I run `p rb_eval_string("a = 1")` and detach, the ruby process resumes as normal.
The same problem happens if I attempt to write to a file or `$stdout` instead.

The backtrace of the program when it fails to resume looks like this:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fcfb6617414 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000543773 in native_cond_wait (mutex=0x15fcf30, cond=<optimized out>) at thread_pthread.c:309
#2  gvl_acquire_common (vm=0x15fcf20) at thread_pthread.c:64
#3  gvl_acquire (th=0x15fd520, vm=0x15fcf20) at thread_pthread.c:82
#4  native_sleep (timeout_tv=<synthetic pointer>, th=0x15fd520) at thread_pthread.c:918
```

I'm using gdb version 7.7 on Ubuntu Trusty with ruby 1.9.3.

Can anyone suggest how to get the program to resume?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand yet what's going on but it might be because of Ruby's `sleep` and the way `rb_thread_sleep` uses [native_sleep](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1ea49760417b17e62a90cce3d736f777cbfd52b7/thread_pthread.c#L1027) (and I can reproduce your issue locally).

Instead of using `sleep` I just considered using a method with a high-cost, that would consume almost a second so I decided to just use an unoptimized `fibonacci` :-)

Here's the code:

```
# fibo.rb
def fibonacci(n)
  return n if (0..1).include?(n)
  fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
end

i = 0
loop do
  fibonacci(30)
  i += 1
  puts "#### i = #{i}"
end
```

Now, you should be able to (please note I'm using lldb instead of gdb, but it's the same thing (almost :-)) :

```
➜  ~  lldb ruby
Current executable set to 'ruby' (x86_64).
(lldb) r foo.rb
Process 41134 launched: '/Users/xxx/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby' (x86_64)
#### i = 1
Process 41134 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x72502, 0x00000001000c4820 ruby`range_include + 256, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00000001000c4820 ruby`range_include + 256
ruby`range_include + 256:
-> 0x1000c4820:  movq   0x16a691(%rip), %rsi      ; id_cmp
   0x1000c4827:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
   0x1000c482a:  movl   $0x1, %edx
   0x1000c482f:  movq   %r12, %rcx
(lldb) call (void)rb_eval_string("puts 42")
42
(lldb) c
Process 41134 resuming
#### i = 2
#### i = 3
...
```